# How to edit input into jQuery Autocomplete before search?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have an autocomplete box that (for the purposes of this example, since it's a simple example) returns a list including social security numbers. These have dashes in them for readability. I want to modify the autocomplete so that if I put in "123456789" or "123-45-6789", it will find the same entry in the autocomplete, without having to add both styles to the autocomplete source. I've been looking at adding a callback to `search`, but I'm drawing a blank on exactly how to accomplish this.

If I were using a search that pulled from an AJAX source, I could simply trim the input server-side and return whatever results I wanted. However, for speed's sake, I've pre-loaded all of the data into the Javascript, so that option's out.

Basically, I want to know how to trim dashes off autocomplete input before comparing it to the stored data (and, preferably, comparing it to a copy of the stored data also with dashes trimmed). There's almost zero documentation on how to use the `search:` option, so I'm hoping someone can help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this would be to provide a function to the [`source`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#option-source) option of autocomplete:

```
var ssn = ['123-45-6789', '333-44-5543', '111-34-9696', '555-99-5323'];

$("#ssn").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        /* Remove the dashes from the search term: */
        var term = request.term.replace(/-/g, '');
        var matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(term), "i");

        response($.map(ssn, function(el) {
            /* Remove dashes from the source and compare with the term: */
            if (matcher.test(el.replace(/-/g, ''))) {
                return el;
            }
        }));
    }
});
```

Here's what's going on:

1. The `source` option takes a `request` and `response` parameter. Basically, you manipulate `request.term` (replace the dashes with an empty string) before comparing it with the list of valid values.
2. Then, call the `response` function with the correct results. This example uses [`$.map`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) to return a list of matches, comparing the term to each item in the list (without the "-").

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/r4SzC/

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to manipulate the term before the minlength check? I am trying to trim whitespace such that "De " would not trigger a search of minlength 3. Tried yours and similar suggestions with no success.