# JQuery autocomplete, change search substring

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, contenteditable

I've got a contenteditable div that contains some `<spans>`, I'm using JQuery's autocomplete on this div also, but it only works the first time.

The problem is that on the first match, the user types 'app', autocomplete finds apple, and a new `<span>` is inserted into the div.  So on the next auto complete, the user types 'app', but autocomplete is searching on `<span>blah</span>app`.

Is there a way to get JQuery's autocomplete to search only a given substring?  Or to only search from the current caret position?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mind setting up an example for this? Would it be possible to strip html tags from the string it is searching on?

Comment: This is what I'm sort of asking, I'm not sure how to specify the string that Autocomplete actually searches on. You just set it on the $("#searchDiv"), unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Assuming you are using the jquery-ui autocomplete you can have a look at the [`source`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source) option. You can provide a function which then can manipulate the search term. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5838154/4202224) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/822452/4202224) for more information

Comment: Yeah, I'm using the jquery-ui autocomplete.  I thought the source option was to specify where it looked for words to match in the autocomplete.  Not the string to search through.

Comment: With the source option you have multiple option, when specifying it as an array yes that is true, but you also can specify a function which can manipulate the search term, in this case you would need to do the look up by yourself (see the first link I provided)

Comment: Thanks empiric, that link was just the ticket.  It's all working now.  Thanks very much!